# im trying to connect an html file to an access database using asp

Tags: html, asp.net, database

im trying to connect an html file to an access database using asp file, here the code

```
<html>
<body>
<%   
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
conn.Provider="Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0"
conn.Open "D:\test\test.mdb"
sql="INSERT INTO db (customerID,companyname,"
sql=sql & "contactname,address,city,postalcode,country)"
sql=sql & " VALUES "     
sql=sql & "('" & Request.Form("custid") & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("compname") & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("contname") & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("address") & "'," 
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("city") & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("postcode") & "',"  
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("country") & "')"
conn.close     
%>
</body>
</html>
```

when i press on submit the above code is displayed on the browser , and no acion is done?

Comment: You said "using asp" and that code *looks* like Classic ASP (I'm not an expert) but you tagged this [asp.net]. Classic ASP and ASP.NET are not closely related. Make sure you know which one you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using an HTTP server that supports ASP in `.asp` files.

For server side code to work, you need to use a server and it needs to support the particular type of server side code you are trying to write.

If you don't have an HTTP server: Get one.

If you do: Make sure that it is set up to run ASP and that you aren't by passing it (i.e. make sure you type an `http://...` URL into your browser and don't just double click a file in your file manager to load directly from your hard drive without going through the HTTP server).